Pattern match about Times default value
I want to divide a product into two pieces, one is the terms of form f[x, _], the other is the leftover factors free of x:
rule = Times[fac_., (fxs : Repeated[f[x, _]])] /; 
        FreeQ[Times[fac], x] :> FAC[Times[fac]]*FX[Times[fxs]]

For example:
Replace[f[y, 1]*f[x, 1]*f[x, 2], rule]

(* FAC[f[y, 1]] FX[f[x, 1] f[x, 2]] *)

I use fac_. in rule because there may be no other coefficients present. For example, I hope
Replace[f[x, 1]*f[x, 2], rule]

returns
FX[f[x, 1] f[x, 2]]

but the actual output is
(* f[x, 1] f[x, 2] *)

In fact, the following returns False:
MatchQ[f[x, 1]*f[x, 2], 
       Times[fac_., (fxs : Repeated[f[x, _]])] /; FreeQ[Times[fac], x]]

It seems that _. does not work. Why?

Can you give an example that contains both factors with x and ones without x, together with your expected output?

@MarcoB Actually OP has provided both. I've modified the typesetting a little to make it more obvious.

Condition seems part of the problem.  Try it with Optional[fac_?(FreeQ[#1, x] &)] instead of fac_. ... /; ...

@Michael E2, you are right. I add Condition for Optional in a wrong form. But unluckly, your suggestion does not work either. Now I use a a rule list for my exception {HoldPattern@Times[fxs : Repeated[f[x, _]]] :> FX[Times[fxs]], Times[fac_ /; FreeQ[x][fac], (fxs : Repeated[f[x, _]])] :> FAC[Times[fac]]*FX[Times[fxs]]  }. But I still want to know how to use Optional with Condition in this example.

"I add Condition for Optional in a wrong form." I doubt… at least I can't find any document page or tutorial that suggests Condition should not be used like this at the moment. And, if we simplify the pattern for fxs a bit, it works!: rule = Times[fac_., fxs : (f[x, _])] /; FreeQ[Times[fac], x] :>     FAC[Times[fac]]*FX[Times[fxs]]; Replace[f[x, 2], rule]

@xzczd In the document page of Optional, in section "possible issues", it says that, Condition and PatternTest cannot be applied to Optional, but can be added for the first argument of Optional. So I said like that. I'm not sure if I correctly understand the meaning of the document. Actually, I was used to writing the pattern as in the original question until Michael E2 suggested his way.

My understanding is, the "apply to" in document actually means "directly apply to". We can see the example is x_ : 1 /; OddQ[x] (Condition and Optional are next to each other), and this results in a warning. It's not your case, I think.

@xzczd Agree with you.

The OP requires Condition, and probably they require Optional, too. If not, then this:
Since Times[] is 1:
rule = Times[fac___, (fxs : f[x, _] ..)] /; FreeQ[Times[fac], x] :> 
   FAC[Times[fac]]*FX[Times[fxs]];
Replace[f[y, 1]*f[y, 3]*f[x, 1]*f[x, 2], rule]
(*  FAC[f[y, 1] f[y, 3]] FX[f[x, 1] f[x, 2]]  *)

Replace[f[x, 1]*f[x, 2], rule]
(*  FAC[1] FX[f[x, 1] f[x, 2]]  *)

This technically meets the requirements of Condition and Optional, but in light of the foregoing, it feels a cheat:
rule = Times[Optional[fac___, 1], (fxs : f[x, _] ..)] /; 
   FreeQ[Times[{fac}], x] :> FAC[Times[fac]]*FX[Times[fxs]]


Yeah, You are right, good solution for my purpose, I should have thought of that earlier. Thank you so much

But, to go further, how to make Replace[f[x, 1], rule] return FAC[1]*FX[f[x, 1]]?

Maybe like this (post-process to taste)?
isolateXterms[expr_] := Module[{vars = Variables[expr]},
  vars = Complement[vars, Select[vars, ! FreeQ[#, x] &]];
  FactorTermsList[expr, vars]
  ]
isolateXterms[f[y, 1]*f[x, 1]*f[x, 2]]

(* Out[421]= {1, f[x, 1] f[x, 2], f[y, 1]} *)

